# Get name of any labelled section

Tags: labels, nameref

Is there a way to get the name of any, not just the current, section (chapter, section, subsection, ...) by its label? Just like the `\nameref` command, but the hyperref package is loaded and I don't want a clickable link under some circumstances. I'm thinking of a command like `\getnameofsection{sec:...}`.

For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{nameref}

\newcommand*{\getnameofsection}[1]{%get the name section referenced by its label as parameter
}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\label{sec:introduction}

An introduction...

\section{Discussion}
\label{sec:discussion}

A discussion...

\subsection{Pros}
\label{sec:discussion:pros}

The advantages...

\subsection{Cons}
\label{sec:discussion:cons}

The disadvantages. As mentioned in \getnameofsection{sec:introduction}...
    
    
\end{document}
```

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `but without the reference `?

Comment: @daleif Without a clickable link

Comment: Erh, `\nameref` does not produce a clickable link unless hyperref is loaded, of which you leave no information (now you know why we always ask for a full but minimal example, such that we know what you are doing)

Comment: If `hyperref` is loaded `\nameref*` generates no link.

Comment: That is not a full example, we cannot copy and test this example, there is no document class or preamble

Comment: @daleif thank you so much! `\nameref*` works flawlessly for me.  Do you want to put it as an answer so that I can accept it, or should I answer it myself? :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all it is very important to provide a full minimal example to start with especially when `hyperref` is involved.

The `nameref` package will normally enable the storrage of sectional titles to be retrieved using `\nameref{label}`. Whenever `hyperref` is loaded `\nameref` naturally becomes a hyperlink. As with many (but not all) link giving constructions, there is a starred version that omits the link.

So in this case use `\nameref*`.

Note that a class like `memoir` has the features of `\nameref` build in and thus the `nameref` package is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean by number and not by "label" since you say without the reference.

It's possible, but it would take some work. If you have a table of contents, you could load the table of contents inside a group where you've redefined `\contentsline` to save the titles by number into their own macros. Some probably non-working code:

```
\begingroup
\def\parsecontentsline#1#2#3!!!{%
  \ifx\numberline#1%
    \global\@namedef{namebynum#2}{#3}%
  \fi
}
\def\contentsline#1#2#3#4{%
  \parsecontentsline#2!!!%
}
\@input{\@jobname.toc}
\endgroup

\NewDocumentCommand{\namebynumber}{m}{\@nameuse{namebynum#1}}
```

If you're adding anything else into the table of contents, those commands will also need to be no-oped out inside the group (and of course the above needs `\makeatletter`…`\makeatother` to work). But since you don't necessarily know the section numbers, maybe not trying to avoid the `nameref` package isn't such a bad idea (although `nameref` might conceivably not work with some document classes).